# Task observer implementation

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I need help cleaning up this piece of code.

```
if is_complete == true
  #If there are time stamps get between time stamps
  if start_date && end_date
    tasks = Task.find(:all, :include => [:task_observer, :job, :contact], :conditions => ["contact_id = ? and completed_date IS NOT NULL and DATE(completed_date) between ? and ?", contact_id, start_date, end_date])
  else
    tasks = Task.find(:all, :include => [:task_observer, :job, :contact], :conditions => ["contact_id = ? and completed_date IS NOT NULL", contact_id])
  end
else
  #If there are time stamps get between time stamps
  if start_date && end_date
    tasks = Task.find(:all, :include => [:task_observer, :job, :contact], :conditions => ["contact_id = ? and completed_date IS NULL and DATE(completed_date) between ? and ?", contact_id, start_date, end_date])
  else
    tasks = Task.find(:all, :include => [:task_observer, :job, :contact], :conditions => ["contact_id = ? and completed_date IS NULL", contact_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can replace `if is_complete == true` with `if is_complete`
2. the only thing that changes is `:conditions`, `tasks = ...` should not be inside the if/else
3. the 3rd case is invalid: `completed_date` can't be `NULL` and within a certain range at the same time
4. use one conditional for the `NOT` in `completed_date IS (NOT) NULL` and one for the `and DATE ...`, and concatenate the sql string then. Then the nested if/else is gone.
5. the extra query arguments `start_date` and `end_date` depend only on `start_date && end_date`, so the distinctions should not be in the `is_completed` conditional.